# question on conditional probability calculation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, self-learning

I have an item which is defect or non-defect.

And I will test whether it is defect or not.

P(test defect | defect) = 0.7

P(test nondefect | nondefect) = 0.75

P(defect) =0.05

Then, I will calculate

I) P(test defect)=?

II) P(defect |test defect) = ?

III) P( defect | test non defect) = ?

---

In order to find these parts, will I calculate following formulas?

I) P(test defect) = P(test defect | defect) * P(defect) + P(test defect | nondefect)* [1- P(defect)]

II) P(defect |test defect)  = P(test defect | defect) * P(defect) / P(test defect)

III) P( defect | test non defect) =  I have no idea.

Please help me to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Look up *Bayes theorem* or *Bayes formula* to see that II is appropriate.

Comment: $P( \text{ defect }\mid \text{ test non defect }) = \dfrac{P(\text{ test non defect }\mid  \text{ defect })  P(\text{ defect })}{P(\text{ test non defect })}$ and you can work these out from what you already know

Comment: @Henry well, how can I calculate P(test non defect | defect) =? which is equal to 1 - P(test defect | defect) ?

Comment: Yes.  Similarly $P(\text{ test non defect }) =  1- P(\text{ test defect })$

Comment: thanks a lot @Henry